# Nginx freezes when using password protected location on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx

Nginx is booting fine, index.html is loading, but as soon as an user sends the log in petition it freezes (CPU going to > 50% and not answering any request). You are then forced to stop and restart Nginx.

If entering the right user details on the prompt screen, it simply says that that the details are invalid:

error.log
`[error] 3612#0: *1 user "user": password mismatch,`

If entering wrong details (any user - password combination) it freezes.

That is my current relevant configuration:

nginx.conf

```
    location /Protected/ {
        auth_basic "Authorized access only"; 
        auth_basic_user_file "./htpasswd"; 
    }
```

htpasswd

```
user:{PLAIN}secret
```

Also tried encrypting the password with `crypt()`

The password file seems like to have been accessed, otherwise I would be seeing a file access error in the error.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a machine restart fixed the issue.